# Is it necessary to implement HTTP BASIC type authentication for all users who sign up for my website?

Tags: apache, http, basic-authentication

Is it necessary, or even a better practice than not to, implement http basic form type authentication for all users who sign up for my web application?

Comment: Many - most? I honestly can't remember a public-facing basic auth site - public sites skip HTTP BASIC and directly use and "Form Based Authentication" and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessary. In fact, it's not recommended.

HTTP authentication is *not* a good way for users to log into your web site. The interface is ugly, clunky, and can't be customized, and there's no way to log out once you've logged in. Additionally, some mobile devices don't support HTTP authentication at all.

The de-facto standard is to use cookie-based sessions for authentication. They don't suffer from any of these limitations.